# Intermittent RDP disconnects

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, rdp, connection

We have a Windows Server 2016 VPS which we use to run company software on it.
Users have to RDP to it, each one of them has its own separate session. At one of our sites, we have poor 4G internet quality, so the connection drops intermittently. After a couple of seconds, the RDP automatically reconnects, but it's very annoying during work.
I've tried adjusting RDP group policy settings (automatic reconnection, keep alive interval, session time limits) with little to no success.

Do you have any suggestions, how to keep the connection alive - even if there is a connection drop? Or could you suggest an RDP alternative with session support?

Comment: `how to keep the connection alive - even if there is a connection drop?` No. TCP is connection-oriented. No connection, no session. You know where the problem is, that is what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, we're working on the main problem too.
So far, I've tried realVNC which seemed to be more tolerant against network outages (I mean 1-2 sec lags) - the connection was slower but never disconnected, like Win RDP.
Unfortunately realVNC can only connect to the console session, not to the XY user's tcp-udp session.

Comment: There isn't any information about the connection such as a capture, but if the connection is being reset externally, that is what is supposed to happen.